# Maintain uniqueness of property/properties values in a class

Tags: .net, class, collections

I have following classes. I want keep BP value unique across all items of Admin_Fee_Prop. I don't know what collection type of property Admin_Fee_Prop should be used or how to define Admin_Fee Class so that BP property value should remain unique across all item of Admin_Fee_Prop? Some times i may also need uniqueness on composite properties.

```
Public Class BE
{
  public string Name {get;set:)
  public List<Admin_Fee> Admin_Fee_Prop {get;set:) 
}

public class Admin_Fee
    {
        public string BP_Name { get; set; }

        public int BP { get; set; }

        public int BP_Perc { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define BP property as `Guid` instead of `int`. Call Guid.NewGuid() to generate new and unique value.

If you want to instantiate it every time Admin_Fee_Prop is created, add a default constructor that would generate a new value for BP. Also, you can store Admin_Fee_Prop in a Dictionary where Key would be Admin_Fee_Prop.BP, and value would be an object of type Admin_Fee_Prop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashSet<Admin_Fee>`, and implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Admin_Fee` so that two instances of `Admin_Fee` are considered equal if the have the same `BP` value:

```
public Class BE
{
    public string Name {get;set:)
    public HashSet<Admin_Fee> Admin_Fee_Prop {get;set:) 
}


public class Admin_Fee
{
    public string BP_Name { get; set; }
    public int BP { get; set; }
    public int BP_Perc { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (!(other is Admin_Fee))
            return false;
        return this.BP == ((Admin_Fee)other).BP;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return BP;
    }

}
```

Another possible approach is to implement an `IEqualityComparer<Admin_Fee>`, and pass it as a parameter to the `HashSet<Admin_Fee>` constructor.

> Some times i may also need uniqueness on composite properties

In that case you need to take all these properties into account in `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. For examples of how to generate a hashcode from several properties, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode/263416#263416).